# Putting a UIImageView into table cell for an RSS feed app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, rss

I need to create an app for my internship, its an rss feed reader app for a news site that I've been working on for far too long since im trying my best to learn and I need to show something to them soon. I have never made an app in my life and I was allowed to use some free open source code. I found one in swift that is just along the lines of what I need and i put in the rss feed link and it worked. The only thing is, the app doesn't have a thumbnail view preview of the articles picture on the left hand side of the articles cell in the table view navigation controller. I tried putting in a UIImageView into the cell to get it started but it wont let me do it, almost like the cell is locked with just the title and description as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

So the table view controller in my xcode project looks something like this:

[image]

(I got that image from google but its about the same minus the fact that I have the date and time of the article under the title instead of summary)

When I try to edit the tableview cell it wont even let me put an imageview there, and when i change it to "custom" the title and summary go away. If anyone could help me to get it to look something like this with the imageview pulling the photo from the article each time it would be greatly appreciated: (Also, I can share the source code via github to view and/or download and run yourself if that would help anyone!)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the attribute inspector, make sure you have the `Style` for the `UITableViewCell` set to `Custom`.

[image]

You will need to drag in your labels as well to create your complete cell.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! (no pun intended) When I do that, the title and subtitle go away. How would I code/implement those back in since they are working right now? (I'm a newbie to xcode here, sorry)

Comment: Now that you have changed the style to custom, you are no longer using the built in cells. You need to create your own by dragging in UILabel controls, positioning them, and hooking them up via Outlets so that you can reference them from your source code. Here is tutorial that makes something very similar to what you are trying: http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/21/designing-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-interface-builder/